# Generating new R logo with R

Tags: r, graphics

The R project has a new logo:

[image]

Because it is much simpler than the old one it should be possible to generate it with an R script! Has anybody tried it yet?

That should be fun! :-)

Comment: Well, some people might enjoy doing a chi-squared test in pure machine code, I won't judge. But if it's so much fun to script the logo instead of using InkScape & Co., I'd have expected a try of yours ... :-)

Comment: Can't resist:   can you program the *logo*  in   `logo`  ?

Comment: Equally important (in the Lewis Carroll interpretation):  what's the URL for getting the source image file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just asking if anyone has rendered this logo before.

Comment: It is asking to provide an R script to render the new R logo.

Comment: Seeing how cumbersome it is to fill a polygon with a smooth gradient, it's unlikely this graphic was produced with R graphics (base or grid). One *could* do it with [`gridSVG`](https://sjp.co.nz/projects/gridsvg/), limiting the output to svg format, or purely in raster (but then it's no different to importing the raster image).

Comment: This is an obvious code golf question and thus off topic.

Comment: @lukeA: See here: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/12/using-r-to-create-a-logo-simple.html